# Attach click event to body via button click without immediately triggering it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What's happening:

1. User clicks button
2. Menu opens (`<li>`s display = block)
3. Close menu function is attached to `<body>`
4. Close menu function is immediately triggered and menu closes

I'm attaching a function to close the menu (hide the `li`s) to the `body` (3) so that after the menu has been opened, the user can close it by clicking anywhere off it onscreen.

The problem is the function attached to the `body` is immediately triggered in the button click function, so the menu opens and closes before the user even sees it.

I'm using jQuery 1.7's .on() function to bind the event.

Does anyone know a simple solution to this? 'bindAfterEvent' or something along those lines.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page-content div.center-block div:nth-child(1) ul li:nth-child(1)').on('click', openSubnav);
});

openSubnav = function(e) {
    // Shows all li tags and attaches close function to the body
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#page-content div.center-block div:nth-child(1) ul li').show();
    $('body').on('click', closeSubnav);
};

closeSubnav = function() {
    // Hides all li tags except the first (used to open)
    $('#page-content div.center-block div:nth-child(1) ul li').hide();
    $('#page-content div.center-block div:nth-child(1) ul li:nth-child(1)').show();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery's `stopPropagation()` on the click event when opening the menu. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zoeexe5q/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ? (Updated)

```
$('button').off('click').on('click', functione(e) {
   // stop propagation to assure the body click won't be triggered
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('div').show();
   $('body').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      // return false if the element clicked is the button that shows the menu
      if($(e.target).is('button')) return false;
      $('div').hide();
      $('body').off('click');
   });
});
```